# Running Scrapy for multiple times on same URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to crawl a certain url which returns a random response each time it's called. Code below returns what I want but I'd like to run it for long time so that I can use the data for an NLP application. This code only runs for once with `scrapy crawl the` though I expect it to run more due to last if statement.

Is Unix's start command is what I'm looking for? I tried it but it felt a bit slow. If I had to use start command would opening many tabs in terminal and running same command with start prefix be a good practice or it just throttles the speed?

```
class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'the'
allowed_domains = ['https://websiteiwannacrawl.com']
start_urls = ['https://websiteiwannacrawl.com']

def parse(self, response):
    info = {}
    info['text'] = response.css('.pd-text').extract()
    yield info

    next_page = 'https://websiteiwannacrawl.com'
    if next_page is not None:
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> dont_filter
>
> indicates that this request should not be filtered by the scheduler.
> This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple
> times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will
> get into crawling loops. Default to False

You should add this in your Request

```
yield scrapy.Request(next_page, dont_filter=True)
```

---

it's not about your question but for `callback=self.parse` please read **[Parse Method](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse)**